# Remove all commits for files except specific list

Tags: git

I have repo1 and repo2. I would like to port some files from repo1 into repo2 (their relative path will need to be updated inside the repo, but that can be a separate step).

I tried this:

1. Remove history for all files except needed files in repo1

   `git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached * && git reset $GIT_COMMIT -- file1 file2 file3`
2. In repo2, `git add remote repo1 ../repo1/relative/address` to repo1
3. `git fetch repo1 && git merge repo1/master --allow-unrelated-histories`
4. `git mv` to move files to the appropriate places in repo2

This *mostly* worked but the `filter-branch` command did not remove Merge commits. I was able to remove the Merge commits with `git rebase <some early commit before all the Merge commits>`, but then the commiter changes to my user :(

Is there something different I could run with `filter-branch` that would preserve the history AND remove merge commits?

---

In the past I've used:

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file1'`

which lets me remove commits that only touch certain `file1`, but I want the inverse here, since it's not practical to go through every file in this repo.

I've also tried this:

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --env-filter '                               
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

As a stretch goal, I would also like to retain the CommitDate, but that is not required, since AuthorDate will still be there.